# Django: get_queryset, помогите разобратся

Tags: python, django

Наваял код(частично скопировал)

Суть вопроса, как правильно queryset пользоваться? необходимо вывести список пользователей отфильтрованных формой.
(Ваяю вебморду для freeradius сервера, взял за основу старенький проект, адаптирую, переделываю

views.py

```
class Users(ListView):
#переназначаем шаблон
    template_name = 'hsCore/radmin/users.html'
#переназначаем имя для object_list модели
    context_object_name = 'users'
#сокращенный вариант от queryset = RadUser.objects.all()
    model = RadUser
#количество отображений на странице
    paginate_by = 50

#сортировка отображения
    def get_queryset(self):
        filter_form = RadUserFilterForm(self.request.GET)
        # проверяем валидность вормы
        if filter_form.is_valid():
            # извлекаем валидные данные из формы
            is_active = filter_form.cleaned_data.get('is_active', '')
            # проверяем активен ли пользователь
            if is_active == '1':
                queryset = self.queryset.filter_is_active(True)
            elif is_active == '0':
                queryset = self.queryset.filter_is_active(False)

            is_online = filter_form.cleaned_data.get('is_online', '')
            if is_online == '0':
                queryset = self.queryset.filter_is_online(False)
            elif is_online == '1':
                queryset = self.queryset.filter_is_online(True)

            q = filter_form.cleaned_data.get('username', '')
            if q:
                queryset = self.queryset.filter(username__icontains=q)
        return render_to_response(
            self.template_name,
            {'query_set': queryset, 'filter_form': filter_form, 'request': self.request},
            context_instance=RequestContext(self.request)
        )


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        pass
```

требуется ещё сортировка на вывод по страничкам, но пока не разобрался как с помощью paginator её сделать(может кто подскажет?).

forms.py

```
class RadUserFilterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(required=False)
#список состояний пользователья
#Первый элемент каждого кортежа – это значение, которое будет сохранено в базе данных.
# Второй элемент – название, которое будет отображаться для пользователей
    is_active = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('-1', 'Any'), ('1', 'Active'), ('0', 'Suspended')], initial="-1")
    is_online = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('-1', 'Any'), ('0', 'Offline'), ('1', 'Online')], initial="-1")
    # group = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

в строчке

```
self.template_name,
                {'query_set': queryset, 'filter_form': filter_form, 'request': self.request},
```

Ошибка

> Local variable 'queryset' might be referenced before assignment

Пока не понял как исправить.

Comment: Не определена переменная `queryset`. Смотрите, как вы проходите условия, в которых она должна определяться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В файле views.py 
В условии if filter_form.is_valid(): queryset = значение, везде задано.

Но если условие не срабатывает, то значения переменной queryset не существует, как и ее объявления.

Необходимо или определить queryset на том же уровне что и filter_form

или 
return render_to_response два раза, когда условие верно и когда нет (не указывать queryset).

```
def get_queryset(self):
    filter_form = RadUserFilterForm(self.request.GET)
    queryset = None # объявляем переменную с ее значением
    # проверяем валидность формы
    if filter_form.is_valid():
        # извлекаем валидные данные из формы
        is_active = filter_form.cleaned_data.get('is_active', '')
        # проверяем активен ли пользователь
        if is_active == '1':
            queryset = self.queryset.filter_is_active(True)
        elif is_active == '0':
            queryset = self.queryset.filter_is_active(False)

        is_online = filter_form.cleaned_data.get('is_online', '')
        if is_online == '0':
            queryset = self.queryset.filter_is_online(False)
        elif is_online == '1':
            queryset = self.queryset.filter_is_online(True)

        q = filter_form.cleaned_data.get('username', '')
        if q:
            queryset = self.queryset.filter(username__icontains=q)
    # вот на этом уровне queryset было не определено 'query_set': queryset используется ниже
    return render_to_response(
        self.template_name,
        {'query_set': queryset, 'filter_form': filter_form, 'request': self.request},
        context_instance=RequestContext(self.request)
    )
```